# transparent background of the view presentViewController

Tags: ios

I am using presentViewController to display a popup on click of a button in another ViewController. But I am getting a black background. I need a transparent background. I tried the following,

```
UIView v1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
v1.alpha = 0.0f;
v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:v1];
UIView v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:10,10,270,270];
v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[v1 addSubView:v2];
```

This displays the popup, but blanks out the screen later.
Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: v1's alpha = 0, so any view added to v1 will be transparent.

Comment: oh ok,my mistake, can you please tell me how I can achieve the above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [presentViewController black background instead of tranparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116469/presentviewcontroller-black-background-instead-of-tranparent)

Comment: as i understand you want to show second uiview as popup. define v1 as property

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing on an iPhone, then `presentViewController` hides the parent view once the presented view is presented, so your request isn't valid.

If you are on an iPad, then `presentViewController` can have the effect you want by setting the `modalPresentationStyle` property of the presented viewcontroller to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`

Comment: As far as I know, that will stop transition animations

Comment: Can you please tell me any other option to show the popup

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution which works perfectly for me.

In the first ViewController.m where I am using the presentViewController I added the below code,

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
second.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to make this work 100% correctly with -presentViewController.  You will probably have to use -addSubView which retains the transparency, and will render correctly.  However, you'll have to make your own animation to cause it to animate in like -presentViewController does.