# View has Black Background When Using presentViewController:

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to present a view controller from another view controller and it works but the presented controller has a black background and I want it to be clear.

```
- (void)showMenu
{   
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    MenuTableViewController *menu = [[MenuTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    menu.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    menu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

    blurredView = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    [blurredView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [self.view addSubview:blurredView];

    [self presentViewController:menu animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

MenuTableViewController.h

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

MenuTableViewController.m

```
@interface MenuTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuTableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *menuItems;
    NSMutableArray *insuranceItems;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    menuItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Action Alerts", @"Ag News", @"Market Updates", @"Tours & Conferences", @"KFB Magazine", @"Member Benefits", @"Ag Facts", @"Roadside Farm Markets", @"Weather", @"Annual Meeting", @"Media", nil];
    insuranceItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"My KYFB", nil];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return @"Federation";
    }
    else
    {
        return @"Insurance";
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return menuItems.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return insuranceItems.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *mbTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    // UIColor *kfbBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0f green:77.0/255.0f blue:139.0/255.0f alpha:1];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:24.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [insuranceItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: On iPhone (unless you present with `UIModalPresentationCustom` and do your own transition) the presentation is assumed to be full screen and the presenting view controller is removed from the hierarchy

Comment: I got it working by adding [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] insertSubview:self.view atIndex:0]; The only issue with this is that the space where the navigation bar is is black.

Comment: You really don't want to do be doing that...

Comment: You're right. I've decided to just implement a new UIWindow to get the effect I want and set the new window to nil when I'm finished with it.

Comment: I'd recommend watching 'Custom Transitions Using ViewControllers' here https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/

Comment: possible duplicate of [presentViewController black background instead of tranparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116469/presentviewcontroller-black-background-instead-of-tranparent)